# Why do lm() and aov() give different results when fitting ANCOVA in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I've read that ANCOVA is just multiple linear regression by a different name (e.g. here--"mathematically identical": [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190984/anova-vs-multiple-linear-regression-why-is-anova-so-commonly-used-in-experiment#:~:text=ANOVA%20and%20OLS%20regression%20are,a%20special%20case%20of%20regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190984/anova-vs-multiple-linear-regression-why-is-anova-so-commonly-used-in-experiment#:%7E:text=ANOVA%20and%20OLS%20regression%20are,a%20special%20case%20of%20regression). and here--"technically the same thing": https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281528/dealing-with-model-assumption-violation-homogeneity-of-regression-coefficients).

So why do I get different results when using `lm()` vs `aov()` in R?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

# Factorise 'cyl' in cars df:
mtcars <-
  mtcars %>%
  tibble() %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl))

# Fit ANCOVA using lm():
lm_cars <-
  lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, mtcars)

summary(lm_cars)

# Results of lm():
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5890 -1.2357 -0.5159  1.3845  5.7915 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  33.9908     1.8878  18.006  < 2e-16 ***
wt           -3.2056     0.7539  -4.252 0.000213 ***
cyl6         -4.2556     1.3861  -3.070 0.004718 ** 
cyl8         -6.0709     1.6523  -3.674 0.000999 ***
---
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.557 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8374,    Adjusted R-squared:   0.82 
F-statistic: 48.08 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 3.594e-11

# Fit ANCOVA using aov():
aov_cars <-
  aov(mpg ~ wt + cyl, mtcars)

summary(aov_cars)

TukeyHSD(aov_cars, "cyl")

# Results of aov():
> summary(aov_cars)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
wt           1  847.7   847.7 129.665 5.08e-12 ***
cyl          2   95.3    47.6   7.286  0.00284 ** 
Residuals   28  183.1     6.5                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> TukeyHSD(aov_cars, "cyl")
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

$cyl
           diff       lwr       upr     p adj
6-4 -2.47730226 -5.536223 0.5816181 0.1298897
8-4 -2.40595373 -4.955054 0.1431466 0.0671811
8-6  0.07134853 -2.857345 3.0000418 0.9979988

Warning message:
In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: wt
```

Comment: The reason is because they are testing different hypothesis. Please see [this discussion for further details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20002/regression-vs-anova-discrepancy-aov-vs-lm-in-r). 

To get the same results try 

`library(car)` and 
`Anova(aov(mpg ~ wt + cyl, mtcars),type=3)`

and compare it to the lm output.

Comment: Thank you @pookpash. What are the different hypoetheses you mean? From what I can surmise, aov() here would be testing the hypothesis that  'cyl' has an effect on mpg, but only after the variance in mpg due to 'wt' has been accounted for (i.e., 'partitioned off'); this is what happens in Type I, or sequential, sum of squares (I got this from here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/6/6.3). On the other hand, lm() uses Type III, or adjusted/partial, sum of squares; but what hypothesis is being tested in this case?

Comment: I think this [link](https://md.psych.bio.uni-goettingen.de/mv/unit/lm_cat/lm_cat_unbal_ss_explained.html) might be helpful to explain the differences. Keep in mind that you have not specified an interaction term at all so you should end up in a case similar to Type II fromy my understanding, which is still different from Type I even if there is no Interaction in the model formula.